# Ensuring atomicity between different .NET Core services

Tags: c#, algorithm, asp.net-core, .net-core, transactions

Since .NET Core does not support distributed transactions yet (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/715), I am trying to think of a way to ensure atomicity in one of the flows in my application.

The flow goes as follows:

- A sends a request to B.
- B processes the request and stores it in its database.
- B returns a response indicating that the request has been successfully processed.
- A stores the response from B in its database.

What can go wrong here is that the process of A can e.g. be killed before storing the response in its database which would result in data being stored in B but not in A and this is something I want to avoid.

I cannot think of a very simple way of solving this issue. My best bet is probably introducing some additional cleanup logic in 'A' but I was wondering if there would be a simpler and smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use asynchronous processes with guaranteed delivery.  IE A sends a guaranteed delivery request to B.  B performs some operation and sends a guaranteed delivery response to A.  This can be implemented with a messaging system (Azure Service Bus, RabbitMQ, etc), or by simply using each app's local database as an outbound queue for messages.  So A doesn't directly send a request to B, a saves the request in its database and some background process *eventually* calls B.  Then B does the same with the response.

You can also do this with "coordinated" database transactions.  IE A starts a transaction T1 and writes to B's database.  A starts a second transaction T2 and writes the response to A's database.  If both writes succeed, A logs the response from B, commits T1 and then T2 in rapid succession.  If T1 commits and T2 fails to, A logs the failure and operational intervention is required.

This is essentially how Distributed Transactions work anyway.  Even with a "real" distributed transaction there's some small possibility that one of the participants can fail to commit.